# Android:Bottom view should not appear above keyboard When soft keyboard open But Scroll should work. How to achieve?

Tags: android, xml, scrollview, android-relativelayout, android-softkeyboard

I am using a Relative layout as root view and i have a view in bottom. When i am opening keyboard my View goes up and then i use

```
<activity
 android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"> 
 </activity>
```

[View that need to be in bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMPxI.png)

After doing this my View is not showing up but Still my content is not scrolling up, it's behind the screen. I want to scroll my content till the bottom 
How to achieve it? Please help me.

[Scroll the view after keyboard open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYcM3.png)

Comment: Include your layout inside a `scrollView`

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

And if you are using full screen activity then nothing will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try including your layout inside a `ScrollView`, it will allow you to scroll when keyboard is open.

Comment: i dont want to write the view in Scrollview because i want the view always at bottom. See the question properly.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this...(Tested)

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/footer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:gravity="center">
           //define you bottom view here
        </RelativeLayout>

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollableContents"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:isScrollContainer="false"
            android:layout_above="@id/footer">

            //Rest of the view except bottom view
        </ScrollView>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

And in manifest define

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan"
```

This code is working great for me.

Comment: when i use adjustResize the footer view automatically popup above the keyboard.

Comment: @GauravSinghal..I have updated my answer....use android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan" in manifest and android:isScrollContainer="false" in scrollview